# How to map a file to its package using RPM API

Tags: c, linux, rpm

I'm writing a program that among other tasks will map files to their rpm package in a similar manner to what 'rpm -qf file_name' will do, only using RPM libs.

The problem is that the naive way, using rpmcliQuery() function, will print the output back to the screen and i'm looking for a way to return a buffer with the output to the calling function.

Is there a recommended way to do that without rewriting rpm lib?

Currently the only options I've seen were to use rpmlogSetCallback() to hook into the rpm logging or to manually do all the DB enumeration done by rpmcliQuery() myself.

Comment: Either of approaches (rpmcliQuery+rpmlogSetCallback or rpmdb access) will "work". Using rpmcliQuery() is likely less code and more portable, but rpmdb access using a match iterator is a simpler abstraction. I'm not sure "rewriting rpmlib" is a fair characterization: in all cases you are using the rpmlib API. What are your selection criteria?

Comment: FYI: note that supporting "Provides: /path/to/file" requires access of 2 rpmdb indices.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I appreciate you are taking the time to assist!. 
I'm working on a security module that will map a lot of files to their originated packages. So performance and portability are my main concerns.

rpmcliQuery+rpmlogSetCallback seems to work great, I wanted to make sure I'm not abusing the API for my usage, but if you say that's the way to go then I guess it solves the issue.